# What is the best way to check NFT that i mint(On-Chain Program)?

Tags: anchor, nft, metadata

I mint many NFT for our game project and give to users.

My smart-contract must check that NFT mint by me.

so, what is the best way to check?

1. check Metadata's Update Authority.
2. check Metadata's Collection Address.
3. is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to verify any NFT onchain is to check for the verified creator on metadata account of the mint. If the collection is set on them then you can verify the collection as well.

More detailed answer can be found here -

[On Chain: How can i verify if an account holds a NFT of a particular collection?](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/855/on-chain-how-can-i-verify-if-an-account-holds-a-nft-of-a-particular-collection/859#859)

Answer (score 0):

You can just that check your mint authority address is the wallet address that minted the NFT.