# How can I verify that a given account hold a given NFT?

Tags: anchor, mpl-token-metadata

Unfortunately [this answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/a/859/7012) didn't help me to find what I want.

Imagine I have an account address (i.e. user wallet, PDA, etc) and an NFT's token address (aka the SPL token `mint`), how can I figure out that whether the account holds the given token address?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `account address` and `token address`? Should the `account` address the owner of the NFT? And the `token address` the NFT's mint address?

Comment: @nickfrosty Yes, by `token address` I mean `mint address` (as far as I know they are equivalent) and by `account` I mean the entity that we want to check whether is the owner of NFT or not.

Comment: they are equivalent, but I wanted to make sure I fully understood your question before answering :)

Answer (score 1):

Understanding that Solana NFTs are just SPL token mints with a supply of exactly `1` and NFT's ownership is actually held by the "associated token account" (`ata` for short). So you can derive the correct `ata` and check the `owner` of it in order to verify a person/wallet/account owns a specific NFT.

#### Example

Terminology for clarification:

- `nft_owner` is the address of the account that should own the NFTs (i.e. "my wallet address owns NFT X")
- the `mint` is the address of the SPL token mint that represents the NFT
- the `ata` is the associated token account address derived from the `mint` and `nft_owner` address

You should be able to do the following (either in Rust or JS) to determine if a specific account actually owns an NFT:

- derive the associated token account (`ata`) from the NFT's `mint` and the `nft_owner`'s address
- if the `ata` exists, then verify if the `ata`'s `owner` matches the `nft_owner` address

Note: `ata`'s can technically be transferred to a different owner and not reset the `owner` field on the account. So the second step above is a very import one to verify the actual correct NFT owner

Also note: that there is likely some extra validation of input addresses you should be doing, especially if you are building a rust program to handle this (i.e. "is this actually the correct NFT you want to check for?")

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the terminology, would you please provide an example that verifies this ownership? My question is that how can I implement this verification in anchor. I couldn't find documentations helpful in this case.

Comment: I would if I knew anchor, sorry :/