# How can I check whether an account is holder of a given NFT or not in Anchor?

Tags: anchor, rust, nft, mpl-token-metadata

I'm using anchor framework and I need to check whether an account holds a given NFT or not. According to [this answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/855/on-chain-how-can-i-verify-if-an-account-holds-a-nft-of-a-particular-collection) I can perform this check using `mpl-token-metadata` crate, but the answer does not work for me. I use `mpl-token-metadata = "4.0.0"` and `id` and `state` are not part of this crate (I've searched for them in docs and nothing was found).
Though I'm not sure the only solution is using `mpl-token-metadata`.

I really appreciate any helpful comment or answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to leverage Anchor Account Structs:
This is assuming your nft is from a certain collection.
Otherwise you can get rid of collection_mint acc and the collection constraints in the metadata account.

```
    #[account(mut)]
    owner: Signer<'info>,
    nft: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    collection_mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    #[account(
    associated_token::mint = nft,
    associated_token::authority = owner
    )]
    owner_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
    seeds = [
        b"metadata",
        metadata_program.key().as_ref(),
        nft.key().as_ref()
    ],
    seeds::program = metadata_program.key(),
    bump,
    constraint = metadata.collection.as_ref().unwrap().key.as_ref() == 
    collection_mint.key().as_ref(),
    constraint = metadata.collection.as_ref().unwrap().verified == true,
    )]
    metadata: Account<'info, MetadataAccount>,
    #[account(
    seeds = [
        b"metadata",
        metadata_program.key().as_ref(),
        nft.key().as_ref(),
        b"edition"
    ],
    seeds::program = metadata_program.key(),
    bump,
     )]
    master_edition: Account<'info, MasterEditionAccount>,
    metadata_program: Program<'info, Metadata>,
    token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    system_program: Program<'info, System>
```

Make sure you import:

```
   use anchor_spl::{
   token_interface::{TokenAccount, Mint, TokenInterface}, 
   metadata::{Metadata, MetadataAccount, MasterEditionAccount}, 
   associated_token::AssociatedToken
   };
```

Make sure you are using the metadata feature.

```
 anchor-spl = { version = "0.29.0", features = ["metadata"] }
```

Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks for your response, would you please explain a bit your code? I can't see any function in your code, there are only `struct` definition if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This should be the accounts needed for your validations. You can do an impl and in ur function u can call this impl.

Basically all this accounts allows you to even check if that nft is from specific collection. But if you dont need all that you can use the master_edition  without the collection accounts should be enough.

Comment: *this is my approach, probably some has_one constraint would be enough ahahah

Comment: You mean I should use it as an `Account` struct? I can't understand how can I use it for my validation. I simply want a function receives an account and a NFT and tells me true or false (whether the account is holder of the NFT or not)

Comment: Yes you should do your validations leveraging the anchor account structs. is this nft from a given collection/editions? or a single Mastereditions?

Comment: It is nft from collection

Comment: that should be all the accounts needed for the validations. Now you need to add any account accordingly to your logic. The only way to check if your nft is from a given collection is if you check if the metadata pda of the mint has the collection verified and set to true.

Comment: check this gist:
https://gist.github.com/belivenn/53085239136d7e36398d299afd6973ac

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! Would you please mind explain that at what point does the code in gist verify that the given account is holding the given NFT? What I expect (what could be wrong) is that is receives an account and an NFT and returns a boolean, but I can not see such process in your code.

Comment: As far as I could understand your code, `validate_nft` macro is doing the verification process, but it receives `metadata.collection` and `collection_mint`.

Comment: the only way to check if a nft its trully from a collection is if the metadata pda of that nft has the collection mint set to the correct collection and is set to true. Otherwise it could just be just a fake nft. And it also check if the nft is a master edition.

https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/token-metadata/certified-collections
Check how this pdas are derived( check the image - Verifying NFTs in Collections

Comment: PS: also de macro is doing what the constraint in the metadata account is doing:
   constraint = metadata.collection.as_ref().unwrap().key.as_ref() == 
    collection_mint.key().as_ref(),
    constraint = metadata.collection.as_ref().unwrap().verified == true,

Wanted just to make the code a little bit more comprehensive so that everyone can use

Comment: I really feel lack of knowledge here :) At what point did you check that account `A` holds NFT `N`? Does this relate to collections? (I don't know about collections)

Comment: (1/2)
here in this constraint .    
#[account(
        associated_token::mint = nft,
        associated_token::authority = owner
    )]
    owner_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,
But we need more than this(this constraint only checks that the account a holds nft b.) We need then check if the nft is from a certain collection, for that -
We need to derive the metadata account of this nft and access the fields collection.(inside collection you need to check the mint and if its verified).

Comment: (2/2)
For last but as important we derive de masteredition from the nft(mint) because its existence is proof of the Non-Fungibility of the token.

Comment: And how can I use this logic outside of the account struct? I need to detect detect that account A holds nft B in my instruction, and perform different logic based on the verification result. Like `if does_account_hold_nft(account, nft) {do_x();} else {do_y();}`

Comment: in my case i would add and and extra fn to the impl nftchecker (manage the logic there)
Then 
    pub fn nft_checker(ctx: Context<NftChecker>) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.nft_checker()?;
        ctx.accounts.dosmth()
    }
As we know in rust this functions throw a result either an err or ok. The way i like to handle to not waste resources if the nft is not valid it fails insta ctx.accounts.nft_checker()?; if it's valid goes to next line. Really depends how do you want to handle, and if you pretend scale the app. I like to let the main functions really clean.